# How to estimate the nonclustered index size before its creation?

Tags: sql-server, index, datatypes, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

I created two scenarios and expected to see the same result but the results were noticeably different. I would like to know where I did wrong.

**Scenario 1**

Create table **mytable1** with **clustered** index and **nonclustered** index on **[OnlineSalesKey] and [DateKey]** columns correspondingly. The total number of rows I inserted: 12627608 rows. Pay attention that **[OnlineSalesKey]** data type is **INT**:

[image]

```
create clustered index clustered_index_1 on [mytable1]([OnlineSalesKey])
```

```
create nonclustered index nonclustered_index_1 on [mytable1]([DateKey])
```

[image]

**Scenario 2**

Create table **mytable1** with **clustered** index and **nonclustered** index on **[OnlineSalesKey] and [DateKey]** columns correspondingly. The total number of rows I inserted: 12627608 rows. Pay attention that **[OnlineSalesKey]** data type is **INT**:

[image]

```
create clustered index clustered_index_1_2 on [mytable1.2]([OnlineSalesKey])
```

```
create nonclustered index nonclustered_index_1_2 on [mytable1.2]([DateKey])
```

[image]

**Expected result:**

both nonclustered indexes should have the same size because clustered index column's data type is INT, so its size is 4 bytes.

Actual result:

[image]

Could you please explain why these sizes are so different?

**UPDATED**

scripts for creating tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable1](  
[OnlineSalesKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateKey] [datetime] NOT NULL,  
[StoreKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductKey] [int] NOT NULL,    
[PromotionKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[CurrencyKey] [int] NOT NULL,   
[CustomerKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[SalesOrderNumber] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,     
[SalesOrderLineNumber] [int] NULL,
[SalesQuantity] [int] NOT NULL,     
[SalesAmount] [money] NOT NULL,     
[ReturnQuantity] [int] NOT NULL,    
[ReturnAmount] [money] NULL,    
[DiscountQuantity] [int] NULL,  
[DiscountAmount] [money] NULL,
[TotalCost] [money] NOT NULL,   
[UnitCost] [money] NULL,    
[UnitPrice] [money] NULL,   
[ETLLoadID] [int] NULL,     
[LoadDate] [datetime] NULL,
[UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL ) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable1.2](    
[OnlineSalesKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateKey] [datetime] NOT NULL,  
[StoreKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductKey] [int] NOT NULL,    
[PromotionKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[CurrencyKey] [int] NOT NULL, 
[CustomerKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[SalesOrderNumber] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,     
[SalesOrderLineNumber] [int] NULL,  
[SalesQuantity] [int] NOT NULL,     
[SalesAmount] [money] NOT NULL,     
[ReturnQuantity] [int] NOT NULL,    
[ReturnAmount] [money] NULL,    
[DiscountQuantity] [int] NULL,  
[DiscountAmount] [money] NULL,
[TotalCost] [money] NOT NULL,   
[UnitCost] [money] NULL,    
[UnitPrice] [money] NULL,   
[ETLLoadID] [int] NULL,     
[LoadDate] [datetime] NULL,
[UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL ) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

Comment: Did you check the page fullness for those indexes' pages? I.e., using sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(...).

Comment: @TiborKaraszi yes. Firstly I created a heap and populated data and afterwards created the mentioned indexes. So, all pages are filled.

Comment: You could have half full pages, or particlly used extents. Without the output from the dmv I mentioned, we are left with speculation.